# Why does Optional not extend Supplier

Tags: guava

I used [Supplier](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html) quite often and I'm looking at new Guava 10 [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) now.

In contrast to a Supplier an Optional guarantees never to return null but will throw an IllegalStateException instead. In addition it is immutable and thus it has a fixed known value once it is created. In contrast to that a Supplier may be used to create different or lazy values triggered by calling get() (but it is not imposed to do so).

I followed the discussion about why an Optional should not extend a Supplier and I found:

[...it would not be a well-behaved Supplier](http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/2558185aae955387#msg_5debebcb556ab719)

But I can't see why, as Supplier explicitly states:
[No guarantees are implied by this interface](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html).

For me it would fit, but it seems I used to employ Suppliers in a different way as it was originally intended. Can someone please explain to me why an Optional should NOT be used as a Supplier?

Yes: it is quite easy to convert an Optional into a Supplier (and in addition you may choose if the adapted Supplier.get() will return Optional.get() or Optional.orNull())
but you need some additional transformation and have to create new objects for each :-(

Seems there is some mismatch between the intended use of a Supplier and my understanding of its documentation.

Dieter.

Comment: I'm obligated to point out that this kind of question isn't really what SO is for, which is "how do I"/"why doesn't this work"-style questions that have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the case of

```
Supplier<String> s = Optional.absent();
```

Think about this. You have a type containing one method, that takes no arguments, but for which it's a *programmer error* to ever invoke that method!  Does that really make sense?

You'd only want Supplierness for "present" optionals, but then, just use `Suppliers.ofInstance`.

Answer (score 6):

A `Supplier` is generally expected to be capable of returning objects (assuming no unexpected errors occur). An `Optional` is something that explicitly *may not* be capable of returning objects.

I think "no guarantees are implied by this interface" generally means that there are no guarantees about how it retrieves an object, not that the interface need not imply the ability to retrieve an object at all. Even if you feel it is OK for a `Supplier` instance to throw an exception every time you call `get()` on it, the Guava authors do not feel that way and choose to only provide suppliers that can be expected to be generally well-behaved.